# Running Vivado HLS in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, xilinx, http-live-streaming, vivado

I have a tcl script to run with Vivado HLS (vivado_hls -f run_vhls.tcl).

- When I run it using the built-in **Vivado HLS tcl shell**, it works all fine.
  Note: apparently the shell is Cygwin based (as when I do pwd it gives: /cygdrive/c/etc)
- When I run the tcl script using the **Cygwin shell**, it generates all the hls outputs, with two warnings/errors compared to the built-in VHLS shell:

  1. At the start of the run:

> @I [HLS-10] Running
>   'C:/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2015.2/bin/unwrapped/win64.o/vivado_hls.exe'
>   *C:/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2015.2/tps/tcl/tcl8.5/tzdata/Europe/London can't
>   be opened.*
>               for user 'at3410' on host 'ee-at3410'

There is no "tzdata" folder in the path given.

2. At the end, when all the hls outputs are generated, says:

   > @I [WVLOG-307] Generating RTL Verilog for 'CalcSpatConsts'.
   >   **> @E [HLS-70] There is an error calling 'vivado_hls'; try "-help'.**
   >   @I [HLS-112] Total elapsed time: 262.13 seconds; peak memory usage: 1.59 GB.
   >   @I [LIC-101] Checked in feature [ap_opencl]

I am invoking the vhls command in a makefile

```
(cd $(dir_impls)/$(tuple) && vivado_hls -f run_vhls.tcl)
```

and it breaks soon after displaying the messages in No. 2, with the following message:

> Makefile:103: recipe for target '/cygdrive/c/path/latency_values.tcl'
>   failed make: *** [/cygdrive/c/path/latency_values.tcl] Error 2

Does anybody know why I see this message only in the Cygwin shell?

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

As all the hls results are generated correctly using the Cygwin shell, is there any way to tell vivad_hls to ignore this error? So that my makefile procedure remains unbroken.

Comment: The second error might be a consequence of the first: Vivado_hls records that an error occurred and issues the second as a kind of summary. The first error is probably due to your language settings. Try playing with the LANG, LC_CTYPE... environment variables, maybe.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
How do I do that? In the lists of Environmental variables (both User and System) I have none of the two your mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If things work with one solution and not the other and if it is due to the environment variables, the best is to print them in both cases and compare:

```
set fd [open "foo.txt" w]
foreach key [array names ::env] {
  puts $fd "$key: $::env($key)";
}
close $fd
```

Use `foo.txt` in one case and `bar.txt` in the other. Then, in your Cygwin shell:

```
$ sort foo.txt > foo1.txt
$ sort bar.txt > bar1.txt
$ diff foo1.txt bar1.txt
```

Once you found which environment variables differ, you can test by setting them in your Cygwin shell before launching `vivado_hls`:

```
export VARNAME1=VARVALUE1
export VARNAME2=VARVALUE2
...
vivado_hls -f run_vhls.tcl
```

If it works adapt your makefile and you will be done.